# SQLite queries always return empty cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm making an app where I need to store data for each day and it would be helpful if i could easily filter it, so i decided to learn about SQLite databases, found tutorial (several actually), followed it and in the end always got the same result - empty cursor.

```
enter public Day getDay(int year, int month, int day) {
    Day ret = null;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT '*' FROM '" + TABLE_DAYS + "'", null);
    Log.d("DATA", "entries found: " + c.getCount());
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return ret;
}
```

Method to insert new row seems to be functional as it returns expected number, but even though this is called just afterwards, it returns empty Cursor. I've read many tutorials and SO posts without finding a fix. 
I also tried metod .query(...) with same result.

Comment: `'*'`? do you mean `*`?

Comment: i'm faced same problem with android P, This solution saved me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53258585/9967174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth using the [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method in place of `rawQuery()` in order to avoid future syntax errors. The following will achieve the same outcome as your `rawQuery()` by returning the data for all rows.

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_DAYS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
c.getCount();
```

Comment: yes. Always use those methods instead of trying to write SQL yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the quotes from `SELECT * FROM`

Answer (score 0):

Use `db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DAYS + "", null);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT '*' FROM '" + TABLE_DAYS + "'", null);
```

With

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_DAYS ,null);
```

Comment: I have fixed your formatting, you don't have to destroy it again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the mistake was somewhere else - passed wrong parameters to method creating the database. Thanks anyway for all responses.